# Code works in jsfiddle and but not in the Browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my HTML5 code. whenever I try to run this file i am getting a black canvas with no rectangle inside. But it is working perfectly as flawlessly in the jsfiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<style>
body {
background-color:ivory;
}
#canvas {
border:10px solid red;
background-color:black;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown = false;
var startX;
var startY;

var toggle=0;
    var x=150;
    var y=100;
    var w=100;
    var h=100;
    var wasInside=false;

ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

function changeColor() {
if (toggle == 0) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    toggle = 1;
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
    toggle = 0;
}
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}
function handleMouseMove(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

var isInsideNow = (mx > x && mx < x + w && my > y && my <= y + h);

if (isInsideNow && !wasInside) {
    changeColor();
    wasInside = true;
} else if (!isInsideNow && wasInside) {
    wasInside = false;
}

}

$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
handleMouseMove(e);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9GcbH/4/. I am using the exact code in my system. But it is not working for me. May i know the exact reason and how to overcome it ?

Comment: does your browser support html 5 please check that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<style>
body {
background-color:ivory;
}
#canvas {
border:10px solid red;
background-color:black;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown = false;
var startX;
var startY;

var toggle=0;
    var x=150;
    var y=100;
    var w=100;
    var h=100;
    var wasInside=false;

ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

function changeColor() {
if (toggle == 0) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    toggle = 1;
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
    toggle = 0;
}
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}
function handleMouseMove(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

var isInsideNow = (mx > x && mx < x + w && my > y && my <= y + h);

if (isInsideNow && !wasInside) {
    changeColor();
    wasInside = true;
} else if (!isInsideNow && wasInside) {
    wasInside = false;
}

}

$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
handleMouseMove(e);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can anyone explain me how this part of the code works e.preventDefault();
var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
I understand the whole code just can't get this through my head???

Answer (score 3):

you neeed to include js script inside head tag from remote CDN or from your local

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your jQuery code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});`.

This task has been done by `jsFiddle` automatically when you've included jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });
});
```

---

Actually you're missing jQuery library in your code, so you need to include it. So you can do:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });
});
</script>
```

And put above code at the bottom of your page before closing `</body>` tag.